# Copy over the row in another sheet when checkbox checked in Google Sheets

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

What can be the way to cut a specific row and paste it into another tab of the same sheet when checkbox condition meet is true?

Comment: In Excel or Google Sheets?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: In google sheet,So far I have tried to record macro using relative references but when I run the macro it goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

in given scenario:

- on **Sheet1** you have a checkbox in **A1** cell with logic **`FALSE/TRUE`**
- on **Sheet2** paste this formula into **A1** cell:

`=IF(Sheet1!A1=TRUE, Sheet1!B1:1, )`