# Google Sheets Log row to another sheet (same book) when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's start with all this will be in the same book.   I have Sheet1, and Sheet2.

Sheet1 contains several rows.  The rows have checkboxes in column D, E, F.

I'm trying to write a script that when checkbox F is checked, it will copy the entire row to Sheet2 as a running log.   I've worked with appendRow in some scripts I'm "toying with", but keep running into trouble.

I've also seen simple formulas such as:   (This will not work with what I need to do)
[[Copy over the row in another sheet when checkbox checked in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890922/copy-over-the-row-in-another-sheet-when-checkbox-checked-in-google-sheets][1])

That DO NOT log.  This would be great if the Rows in Sheet1 would never be deleted.  However the rows may be deleted from time to time.   So I really need it to copy/log to Sheet2 when F on Sheet1 is checked.

I have Google searched for days now and have not found any Google Sheets logs triggered by a specific cell (or cells within a column).

P.S.
I was "stupid hacking" with some code trying to get an onEdit function to check F.  I'm very interested in learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `onEdit` is the way to go

I recommend you to get familiar with [Google  Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) that allows you to detect [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) either a checkbox has been checked (and if yes - which one). An `if` statement would help you to [copy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) data in case the checked box is in the column of interest.

You adapt the following sample script to your needs after investing some time studying the Apps Script documentation:

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var cell=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Sheet1" && cell.getColumn()==6 && cell.getValue() == true){
    Logger.log('bla');
    var row=cell.getRow();
    var range=sheet1.getRange(row,1,1,sheet1.getLastColumn());
    range.copyTo(sheet2.getRange((sheet2.getLastRow()+1),1));
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is awesome.   I've learned a lot from the script you wrote.   In fact, it was very easy to edit and it functions PERFECTLY.   I knew to use some of these functions but where you really helped me was on the "if" statement.  I very much appreciate it and you won the day for me. :)   Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad that it was useful to you!